# GWT: Label cannot be cast to com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.CheckBox

Tags: java, gwt, checkbox

I have grid of checkboxes. I want to loop through it, but during looping all items are treated as Widget. So I have to cast in the loop, but surprising error appears. It says

> ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.**Label** cannot be cast
>   to com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.**CheckBox**

That really surprises me. Could anyone explain what happens?? Of course I can add there checkboxes to the list and loop through it, in that case casting should work.

Here is my code:

```
public void test() {
    Grid checkBoxGrid = new Grid();
    checkBoxGrid.setWidget(0, 0, new CheckBox("first"));
           // .. etc .. ///
    checkBoxGrid.setWidget(1, 1, new CheckBox("fourth"));

    for (Widget widgetBox : checkBoxGrid) {
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox) widgetBox; // here is the problem
        System.out.println(box.getValue());
    }
}
```

Anyone has idea why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Though you are adding Checkboxes, there are many other Objects aka Widgets(probably inbuilt labels for heading purpose) present in the Grid which you are not aware. Posting a screenshot of grid can demonstrate much better.

Coming again to actual problem, all widgets are not magically Checkboxes. There are other widgets too.

When you are  [using iterator to get all the child widgets](http://widget3.linkwithin.com/redirect?url=http%3A//codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/07/getting-widgets-added-to-gwt-panels.html&rtype=&vars=%5B%22http%3A//codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/09/why-to-use-uibinder-in-gwt.html%22%2C%202218871%2C%200%2C%20%22http%3A//codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/09/why-to-use-uibinder-in-gwt.html%22%2C%20383364705%2C%200%2C%20383364753%5D&ts=1413533067397), inbuilt widgets also get's into iterator.

Check your instance is if Checkbox and then try to caste it.

```
for (Widget widgetBox : checkBoxGrid) {
       if(widgetBox instanceof CheckBox){
        CheckBox box = (CheckBox) widgetBox; // No problem now
        System.out.println(box.getValue());
    } }
```

Comment: well, I made very stupid mistake; grid has one label added also... sorry!